# the route auth guard is not called when I try to login Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have problems with my authentication guards. I am using a theme that has all these features already, but after I made my custom folders and files I had to route with my pagemodule.ts file in the main root page. I have done that but still It seems not to read my own module page with all the components I have to show.

It's like there is no connection to the authguards.

When I change my routing page module to this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PagesComponent,
        canActivate: [NgxPermissionsGuard],

        data: {
            permissions: {
                only: '',
                except: ['GUEST'],
                redirectTo: '/login'
            }

        },
        children: [

            {   
                path: '',
                loadChildren: './components/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
            },
```

Then I have access to everything because I am not stating the only '' to ADMIN, If i set it to ADMIN I wont get allowed to ever sign in to the website to see the content.

**I have following code when I try to login:**

```
public login(credential: Credential): Observable<any> {

        return this.http.post<AccessData>(this.API_URL + this.API_ENDPOINT_LOGIN, { user_login: credential.email, user_password: credential.password })
            .pipe(map((result: any) => {
                if (result instanceof Array) {
                    console.log(result);
                    return result.pop();
                }

                 result.roles = ['ADMIN','USER','OWNER','AWESOME'];
                 //result.userRoles = "ADMIN";

                console.log(result);
                return result;
            }),
                tap(this.saveAccessData.bind(this)),
                catchError(this.handleError('login', []))
            );
    }
```

I have tried to put result to all different roles I could come up with and it shows, but still doesn't give me the access to the content on mainpage (dashboard).

Can anyone help me?
Thanks